# How did Ned Stark explain his sister Lyanna's death after his return to Winterfell?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

We know since [season 6, episode 10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Winds_of_Winter_%28Game_of_Thrones%29#Beyond_the_Wall), that Lyanna Stark gave birth to a son in Dorne and that Ned Stark brought him to Winterfell pretending he was his own bastard son.

Lyanna also died in Dorne, so Ned had to transport both Jon Snow and Lyanna's remains to Winterfell. Since nobody in the North knew that Lyanna was pregnant, let alone how she died, how did he explain Lyanna's death in Winterfell? He must have said something, at least to his younger brother Benjen.

Comment: He could have just said she died in childbirth which isn't false. Babies lives are at greater risk when the mother dies too, especially in the medieval era so I doubt anyone would question it to much even with Jon around. As Ned claims Jon is his bastard, which as he's noble is a bad thing for him, I doubt anyone would question that again as well.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder Claiming that Lyanna died in childbirth while bringing home a baby would only raise suspicions about the baby being Lyanna's. That does not sound smart.

Comment: For a normal person yes but Ned is honourable and is married. No one would expect that he'd father a bastard, so him claiming to have done so wouldn't raise as much questions as some other person in the same situation.

Comment: We aren't told and therefore we can't answer the question. I'm voting to close this as Primarily Opinion Based

Comment: It was wartime, with all the dangers and epidemics and with poor lyanna suffering at the hands of a monster 'from a fate worse than death' lol. Based on my impression of the character, Ned was probably laconic as usual "she didnt survive" or "couldn't save her" or "i was late" and probably not many wanted to pester him about a subject so painful for him.

Comment: Although a better theory is he just told everyone "She was dead when we found her probably due to what Rhaegar did to her!" Though Ned appears to have respected Rhaegar so that isn't too believable either.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder then even the dense people of westeros would have put L + R = J together, same as the fans did ages ago. but maybe i am being unfair there are no kdramas and latin-american sooaps full of birth secret-dramas there.

Comment: @D.O.B.Y2.0 Well it's just a theory of mine I'm not saying it's plausible.

Comment: LOL - "My sister died in child birth. BTW, here's my bastard child who is totes NOT her child. #NotIncest"

Answer (score 3):

We can only guess, so that's what I'll do before this gets closed as Primarily Opinion Based. We know Robert was convinced she was kidnapped and raped by Rhaegar, he says this in A Game of Thrones

> "Unspeakable?" the king roared. "What Aerys did to your brother Brandon was unspeakable. The way your lord father died, that was unspeakable. And Rhaegar … how many times do you think he raped your sister? How many hundreds of times?" His voice had grown so loud that his horse whinnied nervously beneath him. The king jerked the reins hard, quieting the animal, and pointed an angry finger at Ned. "I will kill every Targaryen I can get my hands on, until they are as dead as their dragons, and then I will piss on their graves."
>   <sub>A Game of Thrones - Eddard II</sub>

So we can be led to believe that Ned told Robert she'd died of his abuse or something along those lines.

Most people in Westeros though of Rhaegar as a wonderful person, the most beautiful and a lovely singer. It is unlikely they would've believed this glorious man would preform such unspeakable acts (not so unspeakable in that world). We therefore have no idea what Ned told his brothers, family or the rest of the people. Except that people assume she was kidnapped, and know she came back dead.

Comment: Alternate theories "Rhaegar killed her" (unlikely Rhaegar was dead by that point), "The 3 Kingsguard did it", "I was too late, she was already dead", "She died in childbirth and so did her child", "I dunno", "Magic", "Grumpkins", "Winter... has come", "White Walkers", ...

Comment: It should be closed anyways, I just thought I'd kill any doubts

Comment: I know just adding as there's no point me adding an answer with a list of theories.

Comment: You could throw it at the bottom of mine if you want, but yeah :)